# Does Paypal Provide a Full API integration?

Tags: api, paypal

Is it possible to send all relevant details to including the paypal email and password to make a transaction in only 1 step?

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, no you can't.

I have been playing with the api for the last week and here is what I've learned.

1. You can get the users information using PayPal Login API (use the token to process payments)
2. You can charge a credit seamlessly (without redirecting to paypal)
3. You can stored / delete / look up a credit card
4. You can obtain authorization for a payment (requires redirect to paypal site), then capture it later.
5. Complete Sale (redirect to paypal), confirm payment and complete sale